# How to use attribute to map properties

Tags: c#, custom-attributes, system.reflection

I have the following code.

```
public class SyncProperty : Attribute
{
    public readonly string PropertyName;

    public SyncProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        this.PropertyName = propertyName;
    }
}

public class SyncContact
{
    [SyncProperty("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [SyncProperty("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [SyncProperty("phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [SyncProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I need to create an instance of my SyncContact such as

```
var contact = new SyncContact { FirstName="Test", LastName="Person", Phone="123-123-1234", Email="test@test.com"};
```

And then with that object I need to create a NameValueCollection where the object's property uses the SyncProperty's PropertyName as the Key in the collection.  Then use that to make a post request to an API.  So in this case I would end up with a collection like...

```
collection["first_name"] = "Test"
collection["last_name"] = "Person"
collection["phone"] = "123-123-1234"
collection["email"] = "test@test.com"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Google, but that hasn't given me a solution that I can make sense of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attributes belong to the properties of the class, so you need to get the type of the class, then find the appropriate properties and then get the custom attributes.

Something like:

```
var contact = new SyncContact { FirstName="Test", LastName="Person", Phone="123-123-1234", Email="test@test.com"};
var t = typeof(SyncContact);
var props = t.GetProperties().Select(p => new { p, attr = p.GetCustomAttribute<SyncProperty>() }).Where(p => p.attr != null);

var dict = props.ToDictionary(p => p.attr.PropertyName, v => v.p.GetValue(contact) );
```

This leaves out any properties that aren't tagged, but you can decide to handle those differently if you wanted to.

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kGa6tA)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get some type metadata, you should use [*Reflection*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx). To read attribute you can use [`GetCustomAttribute<AttributeType>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292(v=vs.110).aspx) extension for MemberInfo.

This extension method builds sync dictionary from type properties decorated with `SyncPropertyAttribute` (I suggest to use the dictionary instead of NameValueCollection):

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ToSyncDictionary<T>(this T value)
{
    var syncProperties = from p in typeof(T).GetProperties()
                         let name = p.GetCustomAttribute<SyncProperty>()?.PropertyName
                         where name != null
                         select new {
                             Name = name,
                             Value = p.GetValue(value)?.ToString()
                         };

    return syncProperties.ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value);
}
```

Usage:

```
var collection = contact.ToSyncDictionary();
```

Output:

```
{
  "first_name": "Test",
  "last_name": "Person",
  "phone": "123-123-1234",
  "email": "test@test.com"
}
```

---

Note: if you are going to use contact data in POST request, then you should consider using simple JSON serialization attributes instead of creating your own attributes. E.g. with [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
public class SyncContact
{
    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Then simple serialization will do the job:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contact);
```

And the result will be exactly same as above.

Comment: I had actually started with the JsonProperty but then found out that the API I have to post to does not accept json but just regular form style contents.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `SyncProperty` is tagged on every property, this should do the job:

```
var contact = new SyncContact { FirstName="Test", LastName="Person", Phone="123-123-1234", Email="test@test.com"};
var collection = contact.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.GetCustomAttribute<SyncProperty>().PropertyName,
        Value = x.GetValue(contact).ToString()
    })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.PropertyName, x => x.Value);
```

---

As a helper method:

```
public static class SynxHelper
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        return typeof(T).GetProperties()
            .Select(x => new
            {
                SyncProperty = x.GetCustomAttribute<SyncProperty>(),
                Value = x.GetValue(obj)
            })
            .Where(x => x.SyncProperty != null)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.SyncProperty.PropertyName, x => x.Value.ToString());
    }
}

// usage
var collection = SynxHelper.Serialize(contact);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one line linq solution for this

```
(from prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                    where prop.GetCustomAttribute<SyncProperty>() != null
                    select new { Key = prop.GetCustomAttribute<SyncProperty>().PropertyName, Value = prop.GetValue(obj) })
                    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

BUT!!!!!!!! Don't try doing this your self. This is not optimized and slow as all reflection is.
This is just to demonstrate how bad reflection is

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).Select(i => new SyncContact { FirstName = "Test", LastName = "Person", Phone = "123-123-1234", Email = "test@test.com" }).ToArray();

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            long m1Time = 0;
            var total1 = 0;
            sw.Start();
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                var a = ToSyncDictionary(item);
                total1++;
            }
            sw.Stop();
            m1Time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            sw.Reset();
            long m2Time = 0;
            var total2 = 0;
            sw.Start();
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                var a = ToSyncDictionary2(item);
                total2++;
            }
            sw.Stop();
            m2Time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            Console.WriteLine($"ToSyncDictionary : {m1Time} for {total1}");
            Console.WriteLine($"ToSyncDictionary2 : {m2Time} for {total2}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static IDictionary<string, string> ToSyncDictionary<T>(T value)
        {
            var syncProperties = from p in typeof(T).GetProperties()
                                 let name = p.GetCustomAttribute<SyncProperty>()?.PropertyName
                                 where name != null
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Name = name,
                                     Value = p.GetValue(value)?.ToString()
                                 };

            return syncProperties.ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value);
        }

        public static IDictionary<string, string> ToSyncDictionary2<T>(T value)
        {
            return Mapper<T>.ToSyncDictionary(value);
        }

        public static class Mapper<T>
        {
            private static readonly Func<T, IDictionary<string, string>> map;

            static Mapper()
            {
                map = ObjectSerializer();
            }

            public static IDictionary<string, string> ToSyncDictionary(T value)
            {
                return map(value);
            }

            private static Func<T, IDictionary<string, string>> ObjectSerializer()
            {
                var type = typeof(Dictionary<string, string>);
                var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
                var newExp = Expression.New(type);

                var addMethod = type.GetMethod(nameof(Dictionary<string, string>.Add), new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });
                var toString = typeof(T).GetMethod(nameof(object.ToString));

                var setData = from p in typeof(T).GetProperties()
                              let name = p.GetCustomAttribute<SyncProperty>()?.PropertyName
                              where name != null
                              select Expression.ElementInit(addMethod,
                                                            Expression.Constant(name),
                                                            Expression.Condition(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, p), Expression.Constant(null)),
                                                                       Expression.Call(Expression.Property(param, p), toString),
                                                                       Expression.Constant(null,typeof(string))));

                return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, IDictionary<string, string>>>(Expression.ListInit(newExp, setData), param).Compile();
            }
        }
```

On my machine I got a 10x boost in pers.
 If you can use some serializer like [JSON.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) since you will need to change a lot of things to make it work well and you already have a tone of stuff that dose it for you.